# flex: find which element is clicked in vgroup

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript-3, flex4

I am dynamically creating 10 textinputs inside a vgroup . when user clicks a button,  I want to fetch  the text present on all textinputs. How  to do this. My code looks like this

```
var vgroup:VGroup = new VGroup;   
for(var i:number=0;i<10;i++){

var textinput:TextInput=new TextInput();

vgroup.addElement(textinput):

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Save the text inputs into an Array and when you click the button, iterate through the array and get the 'text' property of the input control.